# Weird error I have no idea how to fix

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know how to fix this?
I tried building my app, but I got an error that it was out of sync or something along those lines, so I searched for the error.

Found a solution that said I had to delete one of the .gradle files, so I did and then this error occurred when trying to build the app again.

```
I am new to android and java development and have no idea how to fix this.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugAndroidTestApkCopy'.
   > Could not find com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
     Required by:
         JustJava:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
   > Could not find javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
     Required by:
         JustJava:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
   > Could not find org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3.
     Required by:
         JustJava:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
   > Could not find org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3.
     Required by:
         JustJava:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
   > Could not find com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1.
     Required by:
         JustJava:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
   > Could not find javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2.
     Required by:
         JustJava:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2
   > Could not find junit:junit:4.12.
     Required by:
         JustJava:app:unspecified > com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2 > com.android.support.test:runner:0.5

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

This is the build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.android.justjava"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Could you share your gradle?

Comment: show me your build.gradle file ?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: I edited the post to also have the build.gradle file

Comment: i think this is proxy problem? are you using offline gradle?

Comment: I never had this problem 2 weeks ago, same network, no proxies, same firewall.